# Error when jenkins slave run fpm command (/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory)

Tags: ruby, jenkins, fpm

I installed fpm by using a command:

```
rvm @global do gem install --no-user-install -no-ri --no-rdoc --bindir /usr/local/bin/ fpm
```

on docker image. But I could only execute the `fpm` command in `/bin/bash` mode, and couldn't with `/bin/sh` mode as shows an error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

therefore, build job was failed when running the jenkins build.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure that your PATH contains the directory where the program `ruby_executable_hooks` is located.

Comment: @user1934428, how to provide the path? Is making local PATH variable enough or are you talking about global variables?

Comment: We are talking about bash here. **Local** variables are those which are defined locally in a function, and I don't see where bash functions play a role in your question. `PATH` is commonly an **environment** variable, and it is for sure already set to some value (just do a `echo $PATH`). To this, you have to append the directory which should be included in the list. Note that the directories need to be separated by a colon in the PATH variable, except when running on Windows, where the separation character is a semicolon.